# When I run "npm install" commands nothing installs and I get an empty new line in my terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have been trying to install some packages and libraries like react-dom and react-icons but I have not been able to get any luck.

Every time I run an npm install command such as:
npm install react-icons --save

or:
npm install react react-dom

All I get is a blank line in terminal and my install doesn't go through.

This is irregardless of whether I add --save or not.

It is also irregardless of whether I use something like an integrated terminal in VS Code or my native terminal application.[image]

npm start works and such so I'm thinking its just my install command that is failing.

Comment: Are you typing this all from the command line, or npm interactive? Sounds like from your image that its not the command line. Your terminal should at least show something, like invalid command, etc.

Comment: If you type `npm -v` what do you get? You could try to force-kill all running node/npm processes with `ps -aef|grep npm` and then do `kill <process_id_from_previous_command>`, or `killall npm` & `killall node` and try again. Or look for a similar solution on windows, if that's what you're running

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case npm is not istalled? Do you have Node.js installed? NPM is included with Node.js installation. In order to check open your terminal and type `npm -v`. If it's installed you are going to see something like `v8.10.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just let it sit for a while. Had the same issue but it seems it was just not verbose about what it did - so after 30 secs it returned just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).